# Increment count on click of anchor

Tags: jquery

I have the following code (found here) that works fine on it's own

```
<a id="inc">Good</a>
<a id="dec">Bad</a>
<input type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#inc").click(function(){
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    $("#dec").click(function(){
      $(":text[name='qty']").val( Number($(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm having trouble finding the most efficient way to use this code in a case where you would have multiple instances of it on the same page. Obviously I would change the ID's to classes, but how do I make the anchors, when clicked only affect the text input nearest to it? Is the :next selector applicable here?
thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class instead of an ID for each item you want to find, group them in a common container div, find the input that is in the same container as the inc/dec button that was pressed and operate on it.

This block of code will work for all the inc/dec/input sets you have on the page as long as you group each in a common container div.

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="inc">Good</a>
    <a class="dec">Bad</a>
    <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="inc">Good</a>
    <a class="dec">Bad</a>
    <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="inc">Good</a>
    <a class="dec">Bad</a>
    <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".inc").click(function(){
        var input = $(this).siblings(".qty");
        input.val(parseInt(input.val(), 10) + 1));
    });
    $(".dec").click(function(){
        var input = $(this).siblings(".qty");
        input.val(parseInt(input.val(), 10) - 1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at but when used as is above, it adds a number to the string in the input. IE clicking Good results on a number of 01, 011, 0111 etc...any ideas?

Comment: See my update on @jfriend00's answer with with the addition of `parseFloat()` on `input.val()` - works here: http://jsbin.com/exesiq/

Comment: Added `parseInt()` so it's properly doing integer math.

Answer (score 2):

In case my update isn't added yet, here's the working code:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="inc">Good</a>
    <a class="dec">Bad</a>
    <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="inc">Good</a>
    <a class="dec">Bad</a>
    <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="inc">Good</a>
    <a class="dec">Bad</a>
    <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".inc").click(function(){
        var input = $(this).siblings(".qty");
        input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) + 1);
    });
    $(".dec").click(function(){
        var input = $(this).siblings(".qty");
        input.val(parseFloat(input.val()) - 1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Evaluating `input.val()` with `parseFloat()` will assure that you are incrementing a float value not appending '1' to a string.

Comment: no problem :) **w3schools** has a good bit on it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: @stevemanuel - I updated my answer to use `parseInt()`.  Good catch.  It would have probably been better to just comment on my answer or edit it to correct it (if you have enough points to do that) rather than copy it all and make one change.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're both right. I don't want to offend either of you by not selecting yours as correct, nor do I want to offend the entire SO community by not selecting a correct answer so I just went with the first one. I hope that is ok, and thank you both for your help.

Comment: @stevemanuel **[Drop w3schools](http://w3fools.com)**, and use the **[Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)**. MDN is much more reliable. If you need a good JS/CSS/HTML/.. source, google using `<search term> mdn`.

Comment: @jfriend00 - **I** edited your answer, that's why it's now correct. It had to be approved first, which I didn't feel was a necessary use of Dirty Bird Design's time.

Answer (score 1):

yes next() would work:

```
$(this).next(":text[name='qty']").val...
```

Comment: This seems to only work with the one adjacent to it - not if the order is "bad good (qty input)" only good works in that case.